# Changed a Firestore query and index link is no longer showing in console

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I recently changed a query by adding a `.where` clause after which the Firebase index link is not showing in the console. Can this index link be retrieved in any other way?

Added the `.where('active ...`

```
let ref = db.collection("users")
            .where('active', "==", true)
            .orderBy("votes", "desc").limit(25);

        ref.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => { ...
```

Console message:

```
Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: no matching index found.
    at new e (prebuilt-89214b55-2a7b2673.js:418)
    at prebuilt-89214b55-2a7b2673.js:11050
    at prebuilt-89214b55-2a7b2673.js:11051
    at e.onMessage (prebuilt-89214b55-2a7b2673.js:11073)
    at prebuilt-89214b55-2a7b2673.js:10990
    at prebuilt-89214b55-2a7b2673.js:11021
    at prebuilt-89214b55-2a7b2673.js:15973
```

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to create a cloud function that executes the query. Calling the function will log an error that includes the url to create the index.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I'll look into this. For now I just took out the `.where('active', "==", true)` and do another filter after I receive the data. Not pretty, but it will have to do for now. Will fix it eventually. Thanks.